# Why is str.replace so fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algorithm, replace

I'm currently learning and practicing algorithms on strings. Specifically I was toying with replacing patterns in strings based on [KMP](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/tutorial-prefix-function-pattern-matching-supposedly-kmp/67531) with some modifications, which has O(N) complexity (my implementation below).

```
def replace_string(s, p, c):
    """
    Replace pattern p in string s with c
    :param s: initial string
    :param p: pattern to replace
    :param c: replacing string
    """
    pref = [0] * len(p)

    s_p = p + '#' + s
    p_prev = 0
    shift = 0

    for i in range(1, len(s_p)):
        k = p_prev

        while k > 0 and s_p[i] != s_p[k]:
            k = pref[k - 1]

        if s_p[i] == s_p[k]:
            k += 1

        if i < len(p):
            pref[i] = k

        p_prev = k

        if k == len(p):
            s = s[:i - 2 * len(p) + shift] + c + s[i - len(p) + shift:]
            shift += len(c) - k

    return s
```

Then, I wrote the same program using built-in python `str.replace` function:

```
def replace_string_python(s, p, c):
    return s.replace(p, c)
```

and compared performance for various strings, I'll attach just one example, for string of length 1e5:

```
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    initial_string = "a" * 100000
    pattern = "a"
    replace = "ab"

    start = time.time()
    res = replace_string(initial_string, pattern, replace)

    print(time.time() - start)
```

**Output (my implementation):**

```
total time: 1.1617710590362549
```

**Output (python built-in):**

```
total time: 0.0015637874603271484
```

As you can see, implementation via python `str.replace` is light-years ahead KMP. So my question why is that? What algorithm does python C code use?

Comment: I expect it's still O(n), but it's faster by a constant factor because it's implemented in C instead of having to go through the Python interpreter.  Try making each string 10x longer and see if both times go up ~10x.

Comment: As an example, you're constructing a bunch of strings in your implementation. Your `s = s[...:] + c + s[:...]` allocates and copies data into as many as four new string objects. Python objects take a lot more space than corresponding C data structures. And if you counted the micro-loops required to copy the string contents as non-atomic, it is not technically O(N) any more (though you'd be hard-pressed to see the difference, given those loops are much faster than other things going on there).

Comment: Here’s a link to the [C code header](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/stringlib/replace.h) for the `.replace` method.

Comment: @S3DEV, unfortunately, I don't know C sufficiently, to understand what's going on in that header. Based on previous comments, I assume str.replace function has the same O(N) complexity, but it is written much more efficiently.

Comment: Not really "written more efficiently". Let me try an analogy. A function written in C is like an expert builder. You ask it to make you something, they do it. Python is like having a manager who can't do, but can direct. He can tell an expert builder to build a house. Or he can tell the expert builder how to lay every single brick, how to mix every single batch of mortar, how to measure every single angle. As you might suspect, the former approach (`str.replace`, an expert in string replacement) clearly takes much less time than the latter (your `replace_string`).

Comment: @Amadan - *Excellent* analogy.  Going to keep that one in my pocket.  Thanks for taking the time to write that up.

Comment: @Amadan - thank you for such a clear explanation.

Comment: ... Because in your code, every single `+`, every single `:`, every single `[]`, `==` and `=` are calls to specialised, very fast, functions written in C. But the paperwork (object creation, object destruction, memory management...) adds up, and suddenly the bunch of fast functions end up running pretty slowly. A master builder can make shortcuts; but if you have a whole organisation, shortcuts end up killing people (or making your code choke, as it may be).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the algorithm might be O(N), your implementation does not seem linear, at least not with respect to multiple repetitions of the pattern, because of

```
 s = s[:i - 2 * len(p) + shift] + c + s[i - len(p) + shift:]
```

which is O(N) itself. Thus if your pattern happens N time in a string, your implementation is in fact O(N^2).

See the following timings for the scaling time of your algorithm, which confirms the quadratic shape

```
LENGTH  TIME
------------
100000    1s
200000    8s
300000   31s
400000   76s
500000  134s
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do replacement faster?

Comment: you cannot construct a string of length N in sublinear time in python because strings are immutable. You need to operate on mutable data types, e.g. lists. Then you can make edits without reallocating memory (thus complexity is proportional to characters changed). For constant time concatenation you might need a linked list type (which is not built in in python). Overall python is not the best thing for learning "core" algorithmics, as it lacks very efficient data types, C++ is def. a better place for efficiency and low level algorithms.

Comment: Nitpick: "a linked list type (which is not built in in python)" - this is not true: `collections.deque` implements it. Though it is not as useful, as you don't have ability to directly refer to the middle of the list, in order to efficiently splice.

Comment: can you concat two deque's in O(1) @Amadan? This is the critical property of a linked list that we need here I thought deque was just internally implemented as a linked list (actually a linked list of arrays or sth similar), but did not expose its full power?

Comment: Agreed with @Amadan. In order to replace node in linked list (it is done in O(1)), one must find it first, which takes O(N), or am I missing something?

Comment: Either way I was simply listing containers with sublinear "construction", not giving you solution to your issue :) it all depends on details of what you want to do. if the problem is "how do I write quick replace" is "just use built in one", as even with the great algorithm, you will still suffer python loop slowness

Comment: Yeah, I agree, `deque` is certainly not full-featured. Still, you can totally learn algorithms with Python, but in that case you should not rely on pre-existing data structures (except `list`, since I can't think of how I would replicate it in pure Python).